Properties of 3D Vectors and Lines, and Planes
Non-zero $3D$ vectors $\vec{a}, \vec{b}$, and $\vec{c}$ satisfy the equation:
$\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}=\vec{b}\cdot\vec{c}=0$
Three lines have vector equations:
$l_1 = \vec{a} + \lambda\vec{b}$
$l_2 = \vec{b} + \mu\vec{c}$
$l_3 = \vec{c} + \gamma\vec{a}$ , where $\lambda, \mu, \gamma$ are scalar constants.
Does there exist a plane containing exactly two of the lines? (exactly meaning two, and not three)

Is this allowed: $\vec{a} = -\vec{c}$? Because this would make it possible.

@Dominique yes - how exactly would this make it possible?

Let's say that $\vec{a} = (1,0,0)$, $\vec{b} = (0,1,0)$ and $c=(-1,0,0)$, then you can draw all lines $l_1$, $l_2$ and $l_3$ in the same $2D$-plane (the $z$-coordinate never changes from zero to anything else).

sorry I should have specified - only two lines, not three.
